# Flattening a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

How can I loop through  all the elements in a list of tuples, into an empty list?

For example:

```
tup_Before = [(69592, 69582), (69582, 69518), (69518, 69532), (69532, 69525)]

tup_After = [69592, 69582, 69582, 69518, 69518, 69532, 69532, 69525]
```

Comment: a trivial reduce : `list(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, tup_Before))` (the lambda can be replaced by `operator.__add__` for readability)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list comprehension:

```
tup_after = [v for t in tup_Before for v in t]
```

or use `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`:

```
from itertools import chain
tup_after = list(chain.from_iterable(tup_Before))
```

Demo:

```
>>> tup_Before = [(69592, 69582), (69582, 69518), (69518, 69532), (69532, 69525)]
>>> [v for t in tup_Before for v in t]
[69592, 69582, 69582, 69518, 69518, 69532, 69532, 69525]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(tup_Before))
[69592, 69582, 69582, 69518, 69518, 69532, 69532, 69525]
```

Answer (score 0):

also, the least clear answer:

```
[l for l in l for l in l]
```

where `l` is your list name

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `itertools.chain()` and unpacking with `*`:

```
import itertools

new_tup = list(itertools.chain(*tup_before))
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> print new_tup
[69592, 69582, 69582, 69518, 69518, 69532, 69532, 69525]
```