# String formatting with a list of tuples?

Tags: python, string, list, string-formatting

I'm trying to use format a string with a list of tuples, which has the following form:

```
formulas_and_labels = [('formula1', 'label1'),
                       ('formula2', 'label2')]
```

This should be used to format the following string:

```
SQL_string = """SELECT 
                      {}      AS "{}", 
                      {}      AS "{}"

                FROM   
                schema.table""".format(*formulas_and_labels)
```

I understand that this produces a `IndexError: tuple index out of range`, because `(*formulas_and_labels)` only contains two elements (tuples), whereas the string requires 4 elements (4x{}).

I managed to find a workaround by first unpacking the list using

```
formulas_and_labels_unpacked = [v for t in formulas_and_labels for v in t]
```

(found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643557/flattening-a-list-of-tuples)).

However, I was wondering if a more direct way existed to directly "double-unpack" the list and tuples using something like `.format(**formulas_and_labels)` or `.format(*el) for el in formulas_and_labels)` ?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: is your final query supposed to be of a hard-coded length of 2 attributes in the `SELECT` clause?

Answer (score 2):

You just have to be explicit about what sequence item you're referring to, like this:

```
formulas_and_labels = [('formula1', 'label1'), ('formula2', 'label2')]

SQL_string = """SELECT
                      {0[0]}      AS "{0[1]}",
                      {1[0]}      AS "{1[1]}"

                FROM
                schema.table""".format(*formulas_and_labels)

print(SQL_string)
```

Output:

```sql
SELECT
                      formula1      AS "label1",
                      formula2      AS "label2"

                FROM
                schema.table
```

This could be generalized to handle a variable number of formulas and labels by creating the needed format string on-the-fly based on how many pairs of values there were in the `formulas_and_labels` list:

```
# Generalized
formulas_and_labels = [('formula1', 'label1'),
                       ('formula2', 'label2'),
                       ('formula3', 'label3')]

SQL_string = """SELECT
                      {}

                FROM
                schema.table"""

SELECT_string = '{{{0}[0]}}      AS "{{{0}[1]}}"'
selects = ',\n                      '.join(SELECT_string.format(i)
                                                for i in range(len(formulas_and_labels)))

print(SQL_string.format(selects.format(*formulas_and_labels)))
```

Output:

```sql
SELECT
                      formula1      AS "label1",
                      formula2      AS "label2",
                      formula3      AS "label3"

                FROM
                schema.table
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the formulas and labels as pairs in tuples, you could instead save 'em in dictionaries:

```
formulas_and_labels = {"formula1" : "1", "label1": "1a",
                       "formula2": "2", "label2": "2a"
                       }
```

And then, you could use the `.format(**formulas_and_labels)` notation you asked about, provided the placeholders are properly named:

```
SQL_string = """SELECT 
                       {formula1}      AS "{label1}",
                       {formula2}      AS "{label2}"

                 FROM   
                 schema.table"""
```

Given this:

```
>>> print(SQL_string.format(**formulas_and_labels))
SELECT 
                      1      AS "1a",
                      2      AS "2a"

                FROM   
                schema.table
```